# Simple Gnome Chat: How to get modal dialog?

Tags: linux, networking, gtk, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions

I've created a very simple chat (one to one chat) which works by just sending TCP-packets. The way it works at the moment is just by sending and receiving messages in the terminal. I would like to create a simple GUI that shows dialogs (modal i think it's called) in Gnome like in this picture:

[Gnome Modal Dialog Chat](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-hIyeIWfFyvc/ToRSxqZnFQI/AAAAAAAAGEM/yXi5buduS4w/s2000/chat-reply.png)

In other words just an application that runs in the background that pops up a modal if you receive a message, and then you can type in an answer and just press enter to send it.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Any examples of this online?

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/214/pidgin-conversation-integration/

Comment: Potential explanation of the above: what you posted isn't a modal dialog, it's a GNOME Shell feature of sorts. The extension @rups linked is another such plugin. You can use its code to model your chat protocol. If you want to create a legitimate client, however, you'll need to find a way to get your network connections and GUI threads in sync. You can investigate [GIO's networking facilities](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/highlevel-socket.html) (GIO is part of GLib, which GTK+ uses) or roll your own thing. I'm unfamiliar with doing this in C; sorry. Good luck!